# while and summation in R

Tags: r, matrix, while-loop, sum

I would like to calculate a matrix with a while loop in R.

I made up the number of row as 5000, it can change. But it doesn't give any result.

```
h=1/20 
g2=matrix(NA,5000,1)
        while(sum(g2)<=0.8)
        {for (j in 1:5000){
            g2[j]=(pexp(((j+(1/2))*h),rate=1,lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
               }
          print(g2)}
```

Comment: First, you haven't bothered to match some parentheses. Also, `NA <= 0.8` cannot be determined to be either true or false so the loop cannot start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few syntactical errors in your code. I suggest you read a [code styling guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html) which will definitely help with getting used to opening and closing brackets. The following works fine:

```
h = 1/20 
g2 = matrix(NA, 5000, 1)

#notice na.rm = TRUE below which will remove NAs in the sum calculation
for (j in 1:5000) {
  g2[j] = pexp(j + (1 / 2) * h, 
               rate = 1, 
               lower.tail = TRUE, 
               log.p = FALSE)
  if (sum(g2, na.rm = TRUE) > 0.8) break
  print(g2)
}
```

Comment: Side note, since you brought it up: you indent by only one space? Also, the OP's logic here is broken -- they almost certainly want to iterate up from j=1 until the while condition is met, so you might want to suggest a change there.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for your comment. It is exactly that I want, I would like to start j from 1 to the level where the while condition is met.

Comment: @jenny Ok. One pattern would be initialize `j = 0` outside the loop, then have `while (j < 5000 && sum(g2, na.rm = TRUE) <= 0.8){ j = j + 1; ...}` where the `;` just corresponds to a new line. You might also be interested in `qexp(0.8, ...)` covered in the same doc as `pexp`.

Comment: @ LyzandeR, Thank you for your comment. It is my mistake about the parenthesis. But I want the matrix to continue until the element totals of the matrix reach a certain value. 5000 is only formalised, I want to create a matrix that continues until the while loop is over.

Comment: @Frank, Could you please explain the code briefly? I could not succeed on your suggestion.

Comment: @Frank bad habit from designing long shiny apps :) . Using two spaces there would cause reaching 90 chars on the same line very easily. @jenny I don't know what you try to achieve but when j is 1 the result of `pexp` will be 0.64 and that will cause the calculation to stop after the first iteration. I changed the while loop into a for loop with a break point which is an easier alternative.

Comment: Thanks !  I will add  {g2[complete.cases(g2), ]} to remove NAN values.